# vba access - datediff

Tags: vba

I have 2 textboxes where the user will input a start and finish time. When I use the following code;

```
    Text88 = DateDiff("n", TEXTStart, TEXTFinish)
```

The box "Text88" will calculate the time in minutes perfectly. ie 06:00 > 14:00 = 480 minutes. However If I input say, 22:00 > 06:00, instead of equating to 480minutes it will register as -960.

How can I get it so that whatever is in the start box, it has to do up to finish, so when I input a time for 22:00 > 06:00 it will register as 480 minutes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to control when the user writes a greater time on the first textbox. Because DateDiff expects the second parameter to be a greater date than the first one. So, If is the case, before calculate the DateDiff you should apply a DateAdd to the second Time adding one day to the date. Then, do the DateDiff and the result will be what you expect.

Something like this:

```
If TEXTFinish > TEXTStart Then
    Text88 = DateDiff("n", TEXTStart, TEXTFinish)
Else
    Text88 = DateDiff("n", TEXTStart, DateAdd("d", 1, TEXTFinish))
End If
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, this works a treat!